# Elasticsearch search on first element of nested field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working with nested on elasticsearch and want to query on only first element of nested range filter. Example: User has many departments and each department has name and started_date.

```
{ 
  "users" : { 
    "name" : User1,
    "departments" : [ 
      { 
        "name" : "BO"
        "started_date": "2018/07/01"
      },
      { 
        "name" : "Develop"
        "started_date": "2018/07/11"
      },
      { 
        "name" : "Design"
        "started_date": "2018/07/31"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

=> current department of user is "Develop". How Can I make query base on current department? Example: I search "Develop" => return User1. But I search "BO" => not return User1
Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: How do you determine current department?

Comment: the current department is the closest moment in the past base on started_date. example. Today is 26-07-2018, so current department is Develop. If today is 31-07-2018, current department is Design.